# Xcode 5.0 Crash on 10.9

Tags: xcode, macos, crash, osx-mavericks

Last night I updated my mac to 10.9. I can open Xcode to the welcome window, but when I click open a project it crashes.

[Console Crash Log](http://d.pr/n/f3E9)

Thanks in advance. Hopefully I can get this issue solved.

Comment: As 10.9 hasn't been released yet, and is under NDA, you may get a better response on the Apple Dev Forums.

Comment: @JohnT Thanks for the advice. Ill ask something on there.

Comment: Mavericks is still under Apple NDA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by updating to Developer Preview 6 via MacAppStore.